# Where to store versioned/historized records?

Tags: sql-server-2012, data-versioning

In our application we are using versioning records using triggers. The application is supposed to handle millions of records in the future and the history/versioning tables are there to ensure that there is an audit trail for various transactions.

Currently everything is stored into one database. My concern is that these tables will bloat the transactional database, and I really want to move all record history into another database mainly because:

1. transactional database can be backed up more frequently since it is smaller.
2. indices can be scheduled to be rebuilt more frequently on the transactional db.
3. The history can be archived more easily if needed.

Are there any performance advantages to choosing this strategy or is the extra database another moving part which is not needed? What is the prescribed solution for this sort of thing?

Comment: You should be able to easily change your triggers to write the old version of an updated row (or an entire deleted row) to a different table in a different database.

Comment: On top, anything goes as long as you have tiny data amounts. And millions of records ARE tiny.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). SQL Server essentially creates journal tables and then automatically reads from the transaction log and fills in the journal tables with information about DML operations on the original table.

To save space, we compress the journal tables. This means your journal tables are stored in the same database, but if you are having space issues, you could offload them to a different file/filegroup and store that on a different disk.

The journal tables are in a separate schema so you could exclude that entire schema from your short-term backups and only include them in your long-term backups.

Comment: Given that CDC does not capture *who* or *when*, I'm not sure I'd describe it as "journaling". It is a feature designed for incremental loads of staging tables; it is not designed for auditing.

Comment: It's pretty easy to track who's making the change. We track when and who made the changes with defaults and we track interface users. It works perfectly well for auditing and has been for quite some time. It's a much simpler solution compared to triggers and requires far less up front coding and intervention.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer having a dedicated database just for the audited records, as I like to keep the database 'clean'

If there's a problem with the database performance, or any other, I don't have to think whether it's related to the version history records or the production database. 
You're right that in time, the versioning history can become larger than the actual records you're versioning, so you should archive the records every now and then. I wouldn't consider having one more database as a burden - just schedule it backups and archive it as needed

If you have several databases that you're versioning - you can store them all in a single database and thus have it all in one place (this of course requires adding a database ID to the records saved)